# Need to create a table that will be referencial to 3 other tables, but without having to repeat data

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

I'm trying to create a flow on the data base which I will have a Table that will be will called Xtype, and that table will be referential to 3 other tables called,  Xtype1, Xtype2, Xtype3,  but when I create a record and I select the primary Xtype for that record It only will only be stored in the appropriated table without creating extra data on the other tables,  and later use it for reference to create VIEW's and SELECT's, I know that I will be dealing with referential integrity, relational ID, and UNION statement, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: My gut response is "Xtype1, Xtype2, Xtype3" tables mean you're doing it wrong. Can you be more elaborate on what you're going for here?

Comment: Give some examples of the data that you need to store/model. What's the use-case?

Comment: lets say Xtype is the main table tah deals with jobs, (is used for all types o jobs) Xtype1 will deal with funds(money) that will be used to create jobs and keep track of the funds and balances, Xtype2 will deal with vacancies (no money tracked just the slots) and type3 will deal also with jobs but is not dependent on either money or slots,

I just want that, when I create a record for a person I can designated a job type and keep track of it, with out repeating the data on the database within the other tables and later refrence the difrent types for a VIEW

Comment: Also I think I got to deal with Cascading Referential Integrity Constraints in order to make it work,.........I think..